# Enable GPIO interrupt from scratch

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, interrupt

I tried to implement code for GPIO interrupt from scratch, but it doesn't work.
I tried to debug and see the content of every register I use, they seems ok.
I post the related part of code I created, can someone help me to find the error?

The following part of code is used in order to initialize the GPIO port, in this case I show the part related to the interrupt mode configuration.

```
void GPIO_Init(GPIO_handle_t *pGPIOHandle){
        ....

        //Other non interrupt related code
        
        ....

        //Interrupt mode

        if(pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinMode == GPIO_MODE_IT_RT){

            //Set EXTI to generate an interrupt if rising edge occur and clear of the falling edge
            EXTI->RTSR1 |= (1 << (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));
            EXTI->FTSR1 &= ~(1 << (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));

        }else if(pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinMode ==GPIO_MODE_IT_FT){

            //Set EXTI to generate an interrupt if falling edge occur and clear of the rising edge
            EXTI->FTSR1 |= (1 << (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));
            EXTI->RTSR1 &= ~(1 << (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));

        }else if(pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinMode ==GPIO_MODE_IT_RFT){

            //Set EXTI to generate an interrupt if rising edge occur and set of the falling edge
            EXTI->RTSR1 |= (1 << (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));
            EXTI->FTSR1 |= (1 << (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));

        }

        //Configure the SYSCFG register for the mux selector
        uint8_t EXTICRx_Index;                      //EXTICRx index; 0, 1, 2, 3
        uint8_t EXTICRx_Position;                   //Position inside the EXTICRx

        __RCC_SYSCFG_ENABLE_CLK();                  //Clock enable for SYSCFGs

        EXTICRx_Index = pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber / 4;
        EXTICRx_Position = pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber % 4;

        if (pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx == GPIOA){
            //Clear and set
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] &= ~(0xf << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] |= (0x0 << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
        }else if(pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx == GPIOB){
            //Clear and set
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] &= ~(0xf << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] |= (0x1 << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
        }else if(pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx == GPIOC){
            //Clear and set
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] &= ~(0xf << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] |= (0x2 << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
        }else if(pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx == GPIOD){
            //Clear and set
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] &= ~(0xf << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] |= (0x3 << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
        }else if(pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx == GPIOE){
            //Clear and set
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] &= ~(0xf << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] |= (0x4 << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
        }else if(pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx == GPIOF){
            //Clear and set
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] &= ~(0xf << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] |= (0x5 << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
        }else if(pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx == GPIOG){
            //Clear and set
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] &= ~(0xf << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] |= (0x6 << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
        }else if(pGPIOHandle->pGPIOx == GPIOH){
            //Clear and set
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] &= ~(0xf << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
            SYSFG->EXTICR[EXTICRx_Index] |= (0x7 << (4 * EXTICRx_Position));
        }

        //Enable the interrupt for that pin
        EXTI->IMR1 |= (1 << (pGPIOHandle->GPIO_PinConfig.GPIO_PinNumber));

    }

    ....
    
    //Other no interrupt related code

    ....
```

This part of code configures the NVIC in order to enable the interrupt for that IRQNumber.

```
void GPIO_IT_Config(uint8_t IRQNumber, uint8_t EnOrDi){

    if(EnOrDi == ENABLE){

        if(IRQNumber <= 31){

            *(NVIC_ISER0) |= (1 << IRQNumber);

        }else if(IRQNumber > 31 && IRQNumber < 64){

            *(NVIC_ISER1) |= (1 << (IRQNumber % 32));

        }else if(IRQNumber > 63 && IRQNumber < 96){

            *(NVIC_ISER2) |= (1 << (IRQNumber % 64));
        }

    }else if(EnOrDi == DISABLE){

        if(IRQNumber <= 31){

            *(NVIC_ICER0) |= (1 << IRQNumber);

        }else if(IRQNumber > 31 && IRQNumber < 64){

            *(NVIC_ICER1) |= (1 << (IRQNumber % 32));

        }else if(IRQNumber > 63 && IRQNumber < 96){

            *(NVIC_ICER2) |= (1 << (IRQNumber % 64));

        }
    }


}
```

This function sets the interrupt priority.

```
void GPIO_IT_Priority(uint8_t IRQNumber, uint32_t IRQPriority){

    //1. first lets find out the ipr register
    uint8_t iprx = IRQNumber / 4;
    uint8_t iprx_section  = IRQNumber % 4 ;

    uint8_t shift_amount = ( 8 * iprx_section) + ( 8 - 4) ;

    *(  NVIC_PR_BASE_ADDR + iprx ) |=  ( IRQPriority << shift_amount );
}
```

Comment: Is there some compelling reason for not using the CMSIS functions for NVIC priority manipulations and enable/disable? Those we know work.

Comment: @andy mango , I would like realize my code from scartch in order to improve my understanding about embedded coding

Comment: I solved it by myself. The mistake was that I didn't program the GPIO MODE register as an input.

Comment: glad you found the problem.